# Error while trying to use pandas to read a csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv("trial.csv")
```

The above code is used to read a simple csv file. But I keep getting the following error

```
File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1748, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 890, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:10862)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 912, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:11138)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 989, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:12175)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1117, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:14136)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1169, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:14972)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1273, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:17119)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1289, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:17347)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1524, in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8 (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:23041)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 43: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: please try --  df = pandas.read_csv("trial.csv", encoding='latin-1')

Comment: adding encoding flag worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

Hi sorry I am so late to this, please change your code to the below and see if that works.

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv("trial.csv", encoding="ISO-8859-1")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv("trial.csv", "rb")
```

if none of the suggestions above worked, "rb" read binary might do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Your parser is trying to parse `utf-8` data, but your file seems to be in another encoding (or there could just be an invalid character).

Try to instruct the parser to parse as `plain ascii`, perhaps with some codepage (I don't know Python, so can't help with that).

---

Looks like you need to use the [`encoding`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) parameter.

Here is the [list with possible encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).

Answer (score 0):

```
store=pd.read_csv('Super_Store.csv', encoding='windows-1252')
```

We just need to tell Python the actual encoding of this file. After some trail and error, I figured out that it was in `windows-1252` encoding.

This is probably because these files were saved on a Windows computer at some point and this was the default character encoding for that computer.
For details go to :
[HTML Windows-1252 (ANSI) Reference](http://%22https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ansi.asp%22)